# SKSpriteNode image not displaying

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

When the view is presented, I would like the image named "Player" (set) which is in my `images.xcassets` to show on the scene.

Currently the scene just loads up blue. Not sure why, as even when adding a color to change the image color did nothing.

```
import SpriteKit

class CharacterScene: SKScene {

    var Circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        Circle.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
        Circle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        Circle.color = SKColor.brownColor()
        self.addChild(Circle)

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems I need more code to detect where the issue is. Can you reproduce the problem using a sample project?

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can reproduce this in another project.

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by presenting a new scene, `CharacterScene` or something else except the code you posted?

Comment: The only thing additional to the code I posted was header labels. And I am calling it by `self.scene?.view?.presentScene(CharacterScene(), transition: SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 0.3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `size` of `CharacterScene` before presenting it on the screen. Here you go:

```
self.scene!.view!.presentScene(CharacterScene(size: self.scene!.size), transition: SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 0.3))
```